# AES128-CBC "bad magic number" and "error reading input file"

Tags: bash, encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes

I am trying to decrypt a file (`part444.txt`) with message:

```
y2EdLtmNQsZkvwwf8jf3fM6c1thfzF0sQfblayGIBik=
```

This is base64 encoded encrypted text under 128 bit AES in CBC mode. It is not padded. The IV is the first 16 bytes of the encrypted text and the key is `h4ckth1sk3yp4d16`.

I know that people received the bad magic number error from problems with Base64 but now I get the "error reading input file" and not sure where to go from here.

I have tried:

```
openssl enc -base64 -d part444.txt | openssl aes-128-cbc -d -k h4ckth1sk3yp4d16
```

Why am I encountering the errors *"bad magic number"* and *"error reading input file"*?

Answer (score 7):

This is sort of a pain to do with openssl, because openssl's encryption makes assumptions about padding and deriving a salted key from the entered password that you have to deliberately turn off.

It's much easier to do in python with say [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/), where these assumptions aren't made.

```
>>> import base64
>>> data = base64.b64decode('y2EdLtmNQsZkvwwf8jf3fM6c1thfzF0sQfblayGIBik=')
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> aes_crypter = AES.new('h4ckth1sk3yp4d16',  AES.MODE_CBC, data[:16])
>>> aes_crypter.decrypt(data[16:]) # this gives the encrypted secret.
```

It is possible to do this with openssl, but you have to read the base64 encoded data -- take out the first 16 bytes and remember it as your `$IV` (after encoding it back to hex that openssl expects), start reading all the bytes after the first 16 and remember it as the `$CIPHERTEXT` (and say re-encode in base64).  Similar for the `$KEY`, you have to convert it from ASCII to bytes in hex.  Assuming you stored these in variables, then the following would work:

```
IV=`base64 -d part444.txt | xxd -p -l 16`
CIPHERTEXT=`base64 -d part444.txt | cut -b 17- | base64`
KEY=`echo -n h4ckth1sk3yp4d16 |xxd -p`

echo $CIPHERTEXT | openssl aes-128-cbc -d -a  -nopad -K $KEY -iv $IV && echo ""
```

Note `base64 -d` decodes base64 to binary (using base64 from GNU coreutils; on BSD replace with `base64 -D`), `base64` b64 encodes binary data, `cut -b 17-` reads from the 17th byte of data to the end of the file, and `xxd -p` converts binary to hex.

Comment: Its a lot to do in a shell script. `cut -b 16-` would probably help isolate the ciphertext.

Comment: @jww - Yeah it's a little annoying to do in the command line (for reasons like off-by-one errors; e.g., should be `cut -b 17-`), but definitely doable.

Comment: thanks for the "deliberately turn off" advice for salt!